# boost::Beast error The WebSocket frame payload was not valid utf8

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, boost-asio, boost-beast

An error is passed to the callback function during the async_read operation. When displaying this error, the following line is printed

> boost::Beast error The WebSocket frame payload was not valid utf8

How to solve this problem? I am transferring binary data via ws, I do not need to encode it to utf8. As a last resort, how to make the message sent by the client to the server valid?

Client code where I am sending 2 serialized protobuf messages. The first message arrives, the second one crashes.

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "OrderManagement.grpc.pb.h"
namespace beast = boost::beast;      
namespace http = beast::http;          
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; 
namespace net = boost::asio;        
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;     

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        try
        {
    
            std::string host = "127.0.0.1";
            std::string port = "8000";
            net::io_context ioc;
            tcp::resolver resolver{ioc};
            websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws{ioc};
            auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);
            auto ep = net::connect(ws.next_layer(), results);
            host += ':' + port;
            ws.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
                    [](websocket::request_type& req)
                    {
                        req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                                std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                                " websocket-client-coro");
                    }));
            
            ws.handshake(host, "/");
            MailTaxi::DriverIdentification identification;
            identification.set_driverid(1);
            identification.set_token("1111111111");
            MailTaxi::Coordinate coordinate;
            coordinate.set_latitude(56.211);
            coordinate.set_longitude(123.21413);
            std::string text("1");
            text[0] = 0x01;
            // Send the message
            ws.write(net::buffer(text + identification.SerializeAsString()));
    
    
            int test = 1;
            while (test) {
                std::cin >> test;
                ws.write(net::buffer(text + coordinate.SerializeAsString()));
            }
            ws.close(websocket::close_code::normal);
        }
    
        catch(std::exception const& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sending messages flagged as text or binary? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @Alan Birtles, Added client code that I use to send messages. In addition to the part with the sending of messages itself, the code is completely taken from the examples on the official boost site. Messages as binary not marked, how to do it?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/binary.html